# Locus of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Sketch the locus of those points $w$ with:

(a) $|{w-1}|=|w+1|$

(b) $Im(w)>-2$

Solution:

(a) If we let $w=x+iy$, then we have,

$|w-1|=|w+1|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $|(x-1)+iy|=|(x+1)+iy|$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(x-1)^2=(x+1)^2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x-1=\pm(x+1)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=0$

Thus, the locus of desired $w\in\mathbb{C}$ are those that have real part $0$. Graphically, this will be all points $P(x,y)$ which lie on the y-axis.

(b) Here, this would be the set of all $w\in\mathbb{C}$ that have imaginary part greater than 2. Graphically, this would correspond to the set of points $P(x,y)$ that lie above the horizontal line $y=-2$.

Please check my work for correctness. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are correct.  Here is a shorter answer for (a).  The given equality says that $w$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment connecting $-1$ and $+1$.  This perpendicular bisector is obviously the $y$-axis, or $\text{Re}(w)=0$.  Alternatively, show that $$4\,\text{Re}(w)=2(w+\bar{w})=(w+1)(\bar w+1)-(w-1)(\bar w-1)=0\,.$$

Comment: Do you mean $Re(w)=0$?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed now.